# What is the best way to describe changing between Mobile and Desktop versions of a site?

Tags: mobile

In the footer of my application I have the following two links:

**Mobile Version | Full Site**

I believe this should be:

**Mobile Version | Desktop Version**

However, I would like to know if there is a standard for this and also what the opinion is out there. I think *Mobile Version | Full site* is a bit confusing as it almost leads you to believe that you’re missing something when you have ‘Mobile Version’ selected and you can click ‘Full site’ to get more content/functionality etc even when on a mobile device.

Thanks,
Picco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about the standard. But I like the approach where only the link that you're currently not on is present.

So on the mobile site there is a link to : Rich Version

So on the full site there is a link to : Mobile Version

And I definitely agree with @ficher on the auto sensing of the site in the first instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I agree with the auto-detection and also only showing the correct links. I would tend to side with Mobile Version | Desktop Version though.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend **redirecting** the user automatically if you have two different sites, but that you might already do... in that case maybe you can have something like "see mobile version of this page" and "see full version of this page" when he first arrives.

Second I can recommend **media queries** to have css on your site effecting content based on screen size. Of course this is not really an answer to your questions but maybe it will help someone :)

**Full version** next to **Mobile version** should make it clear if you are going with your way.